# Analyse AWS ALB (ELBv2) access logs with Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-elb, aws-alb

I'm using AWS' Application Load Balancer and writing access logs to S3.

Wanting to access/query this access logs, I stumbled across https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/analyze-logs-athena/ and 
this SO post [View AWS ALB access logs in one place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384248/view-aws-alb-access-logs-in-one-place)

All seems pretty simple - Athena, create table which ingests the log files and run queries.

However I don't see any records and I suspect the reason is that Athena expects text files and the ALB generated all logfiles with .gz extension, so apparently gzip'ed. I haven't found a config at the ALB level which says "write gzipped logs".

Any ideas if queries via Athena are still possible or if I can modify the ALB config to write plain text?

Comment: Athena handles gzipped files just fine, there is probably something else that is the cause. Please provide more context, like the table DDL, and perhaps a listing of the files.

Comment: Can you confirm the s3 location that you have used with along your DDL and also if any partitions present.If it is a partitioned table then you need to run msck repair table to add these details to table metadata.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Theo. Will try again later this week.

Comment: @Theo - Thanks. My mistake - specifying the right bucket location incl prefix correctly resolves it.